# Crawling facebook and wikipedia to get time resolved data

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, wikipedia

I am studying the growth of Facebook and Wikipedia networks. For this, I need to get time resolved data for these websites. So for Facebook, I will pick a subset of users (say 100) and then see how their numbers of friends increases in time and who gets connected to whom. This data I would collect after every 10 days or so for some time. Same for Wikipages. Does anybody have any idea as how this can be done? I have no idea about how to use any webcrawlers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need FB Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends and MediaWiki API: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page . You can do it in any programming lang of your preference

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. Can you tell me a good way to first learn about using API ? Thanks